# ¿Cómo puedo no salirme de una lista con un contador en python?

Tags: python

estoy haciendo un programa que reconoce si las letras de una palabra son intercaladas de la forma:
**consonante-vocal-consonante-vocal**.

por ejemplo:

```
palabras=[["hola"],["adios"]]
palabras=vocal_o_consonante(palabras) #retorna c si es consonante o v si es vocal y es equivalente a la primera en terminos de largo y posiciones.
palabras=[["cvcv"],[["vcvvc"]]
```

bien pues ahora quisiera para  carácter de palabra ver si la siguiente(+1) y la subsiguiente(+2) esta bien intercalada y probé con esto:

```
for palabra in palabras:
    for letra in palabra:
    indiceLetra=palabra.index(letra) #queria extraer el indice de la letra pero me retorna solo 0 y 1 y no entiendo el porque
       if palabra[indiceletra] == "c" and palabra[indiceLetra+1] =="v" and palabra[indiceletra+2]=="c":
           #desde aquí da error
```

El error lo da ya que **verifica 3 caracteres simultáneamente** y a veces las palabras tienen un largo solamente de 4 o 5  y se sale del rango (para indiceLetra+1 o indeceLetra+2), no es un código muy bonito que digamos pero realmente estoy atascado en esto :(

cabe destacar que necesito hacerlo sin **import**

la verdad me cuesta pensar en algo mas allá de lo que se ve, me ayudaría una manito ya que soy relativamente nuevo en esto y sin mas muchas gracias :)

Comment: En lugar de iterar por las letras (`for letra in palabra`) podrías iterar por sus índices (`for i in range(len(palabra))`), para poder acceder a la letra en cuestión con `palabra[i]`. Eso evita tener que buscar la letra con `palabra.index()`, pues ya tienes su índice. Haciéndolo así puedes poner `len(palabra)-2` en vez de `len(palabra)`, para que la `i` no llegue al final, sino que se detenga en la antepenúltima letra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Otra forma que puedes usar para verificar la alternancia "c", "v" es, en lugar de mirar las letras siguientes, mirar sólo la anterior.

Puedes iterar en la cadena y en cada iteración comparar la letra actual con la de la iteración anterior. Si son iguales es que, o bien tienes ahora una "c" y antes habías tenido otra "c", o bien tienes ahora una "v" y antes habías tenido otra "v". En cualquier caso, tan pronto como detectas esta igualdad ya sabes que no tienes la alternancia deseada. Si en cambio terminas las iteraciones sin que esta igualdad se haya producido, es que sí tenías la alternancia deseada.

Es decir, en el fondo, asegurar que están alternadas es equivalente a asegurar que no hay dos iguales seguidas. Esta sería por tanto la idea:

```
def estan_alternadas(txt):
   letra_anterior = ""
   for letra in txt:
      if letra == letra_anterior:
         return False   # No están alternadas
      letra_anterior = letra
   return True  # Si llegamos aquí es que sí lo estaban
```

Observa cómo `letra_anterior` se inicializa con "" antes de entrar al bucle, para que la primera letra de `txt` siempre sea diferente de la anterior (que no hay aún). Y cómo en cada iteración del bucle se hace `letra_anterior = letra`, para preparar la iteración siguiente.

Pruebas:

```
>>> estan_alternadas("cvcvcv")
True

>>> estan_alternadas("cvccvcv")
False
```